# I want to add number 7 as setting so that we won't need to update it with code change. Can we add this in Global settings? If yes, how? pls check code

Tags: apex, customsetting, global-variables, global

So I have a formula field to check number of due days and I am checking that in my apex controller in 'if condition', if it is less than 7 or not. However, I have a requirement to make changes so -- "**The number 7 should be a setting that we need to be able to update without code change. Can we add this in Global settings?**"

My guess is -

1. Either we can add it as static global integer variable?
2. a constant?
3. custom label, but that can't be used in apex.

Please provide your suggestion.

Note- The (starred)** lined is for which the changes are required

Code-

```
    public static List<PartnerTaskWrapper> getCountTask(){
    
    List<PartnerTaskWrapper> taskWrapper = new List<PartnerTaskWrapper>();
    User userData= UserUtils.getCurrentUser();
    String accountId = userData.Contact.Account.Id;
    Integer countedOpenTasks = 0;
    Integer countedUnassignedTasks =0 ;
    Integer countedOverdueTasks = 0;
    Integer counted7DaysDueTasks =0;
    
    List<Partner_Task__c> ptask= PartnerTaskSelector.getAllCountTask(accountId, System.AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE);
   
    for(Partner_Task__c allTask: ptask){
        if(allTask.Status__c == PartnerTaskConstants.STRING_ASSIGNED ||
          allTask.Status__c == PartnerTaskConstants.STRING_INPROGRESS || 
           allTask.Status__c == PartnerTaskConstants.STRING_UNASSIGNED){
            countedOpenTasks ++;
        }
        if(allTask.Status__c == PartnerTaskConstants.STRING_UNASSIGNED){
            countedUnassignedTasks ++;
        }
        if(allTask.Task_due_in_days__c <0){
            countedOverdueTasks ++;
        }
        **if(allTask.Task_due_in_days__c <= 7 && allTask.Task_due_in_days__c >= 0){**
            counted7DaysDueTasks ++;
        }
    }
    taskWrapper.add(new PartnerTaskWrapper(countedOpenTasks,countedUnassignedTasks, countedOverdueTasks, counted7DaysDueTasks ));
    system.debug('days7dueCount '+counted7DaysDueTasks);
    system.debug('overdue '+countedOverdueTasks);
    system.debug('unassigned '+countedUnassignedTasks);
    system.debug('openCount '+countedOpenTasks);
    system.debug('wrapper '+ taskWrapper);
      return taskWrapper;
    }
```

Comment: You can use Custom Label in Apex. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_apex.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Custom Label in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_apex.htm).

```
System.Label.CustomLabelName
```

The value will be stored as String. So you will need to convert it to Integer.

```
Integer dueDate = Integer.valueOf(System.Label.CustomLabelName);
```

---

This can also be done using [Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm).

Create a List Custom Setting and add the Value__c custom text field. Create a Custom Setting record and set the Name as `'DueInDays'` and Value__c as `'7'`. Follow Steps [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.cs_about.htm&type=5).

Read the Custom Setting field value as String, convert it to Integer and use in Apex.

```
CustomSettingName__c mc = CustomSettingName__c.getValues('DueInDays');
Integer dueDate = Integer.valueOf(mc.Value__c);
```

**Note**: Instead of creating a text field you can also create a Number field for the Value. Text field is generic and can be used to store other settings as well.

Comment: Hey! @Sneh I don't think it will be lying with the requirement though. I have proper statement as - 'The number 7 should be a setting that we need to be able to update without code change. Can we add this in Global settings?'

Comment: Added steps by using Custom Setting. Please note that even updating Custom Labels does not require any code change